# How to center an element when it is narrow but align to the left when it is wider than the container?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

When showing the element in fullscreen mode, I need the element (highlighted with the red rectangle) to be centered if the width is smaller than the screen(container). To achieve this, I used tailwindcss `flex overflow-x-scroll justify-center` (item 1).

If the width is bigger than the screen(container), we want the element to be aligned at the left edge. To achieve this, I need to remove `flex` from classes (item 2).

My question is how can I make it work for both cases: narrow and wide.

[image]

Comment: Thanks to mohamed ibrahim, I realised that this is basic CSS behavior with "margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto". I was not able to get it right at the beginning, because I used `flex justify-center` to align the child element to the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear but if you want to center the element in whatever the size of the container, just follow this code it may help:

```
<div class="lg:w-[85%] md:w-[90%] sm:w-[95%] mx-auto">
  <div class=""></div>
</div>
```

it means on the large screen the width of the **div** is 85% of the body & the margin in the **x-direction** is auto or you can apply those classes directly to the targeted element and so on for the medium & small screen sizes. it's a basic CSS fundamentals but applied with **tailwindcss**